# Order Virtual products as guest

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, virtual-products

In one of the shops I develop, the whole login system is disabled (customers are not able to register or login, and there is no dashboard).

This works perfectly fine for simple, grouped or configurable products, but is a problem for virtual product (since you have to login to buy virtual products).

Since there is a configuration to enable buying downloadable products as guest, I was wondering if such a configuration is present for virtual products?

Comment: can you pls tell me how to allow guest user to checkout with downloadable products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually copied the configuration of the downloadable product, and applied it to the virtual product:

**etc/adminhtml/system.xml:**

```
<section id="catalog">
    <group id="virtual_products" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="650" showInDefault="1"
           showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Virtual Product Options</label>
        <field id="disable_guest_checkout" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="100"
               showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
            <label>Disable Guest Checkout if Cart Contains Virtual Items</label>
            <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
        </field>
    </group>
</section>
```

**etc/frontend/events.xml:**

```
<event name="checkout_allow_guest">
    <observer name="virtual_checkout_allow_guest"
              instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Virtual\IsAllowedGuestCheckoutObserver" />
</event>
```

**Observer/Virtual/IsAllowedGuestCheckoutObserver.php:**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Virtual;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

/**
 * Class IsAllowedGuestCheckoutObserver
 * @package Vendor\Module\Observer\Virtual
 */
class IsAllowedGuestCheckoutObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     *  Xml path to disable checkout
     */
    const XML_PATH_DISABLE_GUEST_CHECKOUT = 'catalog/virtual_products/disable_guest_checkout';

    /**
     * Core store config
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Check is allowed guest checkout if quote contain virtual product(s)
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            self::XML_PATH_DISABLE_GUEST_CHECKOUT,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $observer->getEvent()->getStore()
        )) {
            return $this;
        }

        /* @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if (($product = $item->getProduct())
                && $product->getTypeId() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL) {
                $observer->getEvent()->getResult()->setIsAllowed(false);

                break;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```